# error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::basic_string

Tags: c++, c++11

I have tried to write a phonebook using C++ code with `unordered_map` but I have a problem. In the beginning of this code there is an error which I can't understand. When I tried to run it I get this error:

> Error 1 error C2679: binary '='

Can anyone please help me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <hash_map>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unordered_map<string, pair< string,vector<string>>>contact;
    string name, number, address;
    cin >> name >> number>>address;
    contact[name]=make_pair(number, address);
    unordered_map<string, pair< string, vector<string>>> ::iterator it;
    it = contact.begin();
    while (it != contact.end())
    {
        cout << it->first;
        it++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a problem with the fact that `address` is a string and `number` is a string, so if you make a pair they will be of type `pair<string,string>` . You need a `pair<string,vector<string>>` for values in your map

Comment: pair<string,vector<string>> how ??

Comment: Please take a few minutes and read the *whole* error message. It should e.g. tell you what was on the left hand side of the assignment operator. What you could do to solve this is to e.g. use assignment to the pair: `contact[name].first = number; contait[name].second.push_back(address);`.

Answer (score 2):

You declared `contact` as `unordered_map<string, pair< string,vector<string>>>`
Here `contact[name]=make_pair(number, address);`  you are inserting 
`contact[string] = make_pair(string, string)`. It must be
`contact[string] = make_pair(string, vector<string>)`

Either change the definition of the container  like,

```
unordered_map<string, pair< string, string>>contact;
```

or if you really need your `address` to be a `vector`, then

```
contact[name] = make_pair(number, std::vector<string>{address});
```

If you are using `c++11` or later then `auto` can be used,

```
auto it = contact.begin();
```

instead of

```
unordered_map<string, pair< string, vector<string>>> ::iterator it;
it = contact.begin();
```